# Is the return type of .then() a promise even with no return statement?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) for .then() says that the return type of then is a promise.

So my question is, is there a difference between the following code blocks?

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  //no return type specified here
});
```

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  return Promise.resolve();
  //the return type here is a resolved promise with undefined value
});
```

The second point in the ['return value' segment of the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) suggest to me that they are the same.

The reason I ask is that TypeScript seems to make a distinction between the two and when I have a return type of Promise I must use the second snippet and not the first

**EDIT:**

I figured out the problem I was having and it was not because of this issue.
I had the following code:

```html
return login() //this returns a promise
.then((response: LoginResponse) => {
        if (!response.success) {
          return Promise.reject();
        }
        console.log('Logged In');
        return Promise.resolve(); //I must write this line otherwise I have a TypeError
      });
```

It is simply because the anonymous function in then has a return type of Promise because of the `Promise.reject()` in the if block. It has nothing to do with the return type of `.then()` block but the return type of the anonymous function.

Comment: If you don't return anything from inside a `.then()` handler, the next step will automatically resolve with the value undefined. So functionally, both examples are the same, since they both resolve any `.then()` handler chained to them with an undefined value. Structurally, the second example will have an extra promise nested into the chain.

Comment: Concerning the typescript issue, I ahve a hunch that either you use non-native promises or you're compiling down to non-native promises.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shilly. Made it crystal clear to me :)